# Patch for JBOSS EAP 7.3.3

Tags: eclipse, jboss

I want to use the JBOSS EAP 7.3.3 for windows on Eclipse for development.
I have installed JBOSS 7.3 already but not able to find the patch for 7.3.3, can someone help me

Not able to find the patch for 7.3.3 in the list of updates

Comment: If you're using JBoss EAP 7.3.3 you should have a support contract. I would suggest contacting [Red Hat support](https://access.redhat.com/support/contact/).